# spark-shell exception org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, spark-shell

Facing below error while starting spark-shell with yarn master. Shell is working with spark local master.

```
admin@XXXXXX:~$ spark-shell --master yarn 21/11/03 15:51:51 WARN Utils: Your hostname, XXXXXX resolves to a loopback address:
127.0.1.1; using 192.168.29.57 instead (on interface wifi0) 21/11/03 15:51:51 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address Setting default log level to "WARN". To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel). 21/11/03 15:52:01 WARN Client: Neither spark.yarn.jars nor spark.yarn.archive is set, falling back to uploading libraries under SPARK_HOME. Spark context Web UI available at http://XX.XX.XX.XX:4040 Spark context available as 'sc' (master = yarn, app id = application_1635934709971_0001). Spark session available as 'spark'. Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/    /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.4.5
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.12 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java
1.8.0_301) Type in expressions to have them evaluated. Type :help for more information.

scala>

scala> 21/11/03 15:52:35 ERROR YarnClientSchedulerBackend: YARN application has exited unexpectedly with state FAILED! Check the YARN application logs for more details. 21/11/03 15:52:35 ERROR YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Diagnostics message: Uncaught exception: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult:
        at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:226)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:101)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRef(RpcEnv.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.runExecutorLauncher(ApplicationMaster.scala:515)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.org$apache$spark$deploy$yarn$ApplicationMaster$$runImpl(ApplicationMaster.scala:307)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(ApplicationMaster.scala:245)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$run$1.apply(ApplicationMaster.scala:245)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$run$1.apply(ApplicationMaster.scala:245)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$3.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:780)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.doAsUser(ApplicationMaster.scala:779)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:244)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:804)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ExecutorLauncher$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:834)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ExecutorLauncher.main(ApplicationMaster.scala) Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to /192.168.29.57:33333
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:245)
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:187)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.createClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:198)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:194)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:190)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: /192.168.29.57:33333 Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:715)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:327)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:688)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:635)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:552)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:514)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$6.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:1044)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

21/11/03 15:52:35 WARN YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: Attempted to request executors before the AM has registered!
```

Below is **spark-defaults.conf**

```
spark.driver.memory              512m
spark.yarn.am.memory             512m
spark.executor.memory            512m
spark.eventLog.enabled true
spark.eventLog.dir file:////home/admin/spark_event_temp
spark.history.fs.logDirectory hdfs://localhost:9000/spark-logs
spark.history.fs.update.interval 10s
spark.history.ui.port 18080
spark.sql.warehouse.dir=file:////home/admin/spark_warehouse
spark.shuffle.service.port              7337
spark.ui.port                           4040
spark.blockManager.port                 31111
spark.driver.blockManager.port          32222
spark.driver.port                       33333
```

**spark version:- spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7**

**hadoop version:- hadoop-2.8.5**

I can provide more information if needed. I have configured everything in the local machine.

Comment: Hello @ashish-mishra, have you got the solution for this ?, if yes can you please kindly share the same.

Comment: no, Actually I am still facing this issue.  One thing that I noticed is that "whenever I restart Hadoop and format name node then for few seconds this error is gone". I ll update here once get the answer

Comment: Hi @AlbinChandy, I think I found some hack but want to confirm with you whether it is correct or not.  I have these values in spark-env.sh added. please try and let me know so that I'll put it as an answer.                
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
export HADOOP_HOME=/mnt/d/soft/hadoop-2.8.5
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
export SPARK_HOME=$SPARK_HOME
export YARN_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/
export SPARK_MASTER_HOST=127.0.0.1
                                                                            
 export SPARK_LOCAL_IP=127.0.0.1

Comment: Thanks @Ashish-mishra, I was running the spark script on a cloudera cluster, I see that you have made the spark master host and local IP the same. Thanks for the idea, let me see if I can do something similar.

Comment: hi @AlbinChandy, did you get a chance to look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding these properties in spark-env.sh fixed the issue for me.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64 
export HADOOP_HOME=/mnt/d/soft/hadoop-2.8.5 
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop 
export SPARK_HOME=$SPARK_HOME 
export YARN_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/ 
export SPARK_MASTER_HOST=127.0.0.1 
export SPARK_LOCAL_IP=127.0.0.1
```

Comment: You are changing master to local node, this would always work when master, driver and executors everything is running on same node. What if your master node is somewhere outside this node/machine.

Comment: @MousamSingh it's just these properties that anyone can set as per their architecture. And previously when I had not set them then It was not working for me. Though I have not tried to set up a multi-node cluster on my local machine.